# Submitting 'New' Opens Record in 'Edit'

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2010

Regarding a CustomList, "MyCL":

In SharePoint 2010, I have a customized 'New' form, for MyCL.

When the "Save" button is clicked , a new MyCL item is created, and the MyCL is diplayed in the browser, having the new item.

At that point, I can select to edit the new item, and have it show in an Edit page.

I would like to skip that step that presents MyCL in the browser, and just go straight to the step that shows the new record in the edit page.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This page has pretty good scoop on how this can be done.

[Pass parameter to redirect url in GenFireServerEvent SharePoint 2010](http://mahedevelopment.blogspot.com/2013/03/pass-parameter-to-redirect-url-in.html).